# Order by a columns count where another column has a static value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, count

I have a table which stores user items, the two key columns which I would like to use in this query are **user_id** and **item_id**. The id field in the example is not needed but just added to show these aren't the only two columns in the table.

```
----------------------
id  user_id  item_id
----------------------
1     1        324
2     1        324
3     3        324
4     2        230
5     4        324
```

The query which I would like to construct should return the top 10 users who have the most items with a specific item id.

So for example if I wanted to run the query against the item ID 324 I should get the following result.

```
-------------------
user_id  item_count
-------------------
1           2
3           1
4           1
2           0
```

Comment: you should use group by  ( but why user_2   item_count = 0 ...? should be 1 too)

Comment: and a `COUNT()` function

Comment: Do you really want the 4th row which has zero count?

Comment: I suppose the 4th row isn't needed to be honest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select user_id , count(*) as item_count from table 
where item_id = 324 group by user_id order by item_count desc limit 10
```

limit 10 will show you the top 10 users and order by desc sort from high to low.

However, the above query will not give you the 0 count as per your question. If you really want the zero count you can try this: (assuming your table name is userlist)

```
SELECT distinct user_id, 
(select 
   count(*) from `userlist` 
   where user_id=u.user_id and item_id=324
) as item_count FROM `userlist` u 
order by item_count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't create the database in my local, but I think this will do the trick

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(item_id) as item_count 
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE item_id = 324
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY item_count;
```